# Scanner no class error

Tags: java

I'm new to java and i have a problem while trying to run my program. I'm using eclipse.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String imie;
        Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);

        imie=odczyt.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Witaj "+imie);
    }}
```

This what I get:

EDIT(Runned without dot)

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Scan
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Scan
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     Could not find the main class: Scan.  Program will exit.
```

Please help me. :)

Comment: Are you writing the program in Eclipse and running the program in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're running `java`, don't put `.java` on the end of the class name.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to run a class named `Scan.java`, but there is no such class; the class is just named `Scan`. However you're launching your class, you need to launch just `Scan`, i.e.,

```
java Scan
```

not

```
java Scan.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify classpath that specifies where Scan class can be found. The classpath can point to a folder of classes or a JAR file. For instance...

java -cp scan.jar Scan

Comment: But every other programms works normal in eclipse and my Scanner could not be open. Why is that?

Comment: What does this have to do with Eclipse?

Comment: Maybe your .java file wasn't built or the .class file was written to another location. Look for Scan.class file on your system. Remember, you can only run compiled Java files (.class as opposed to .java). The classpath should point to where your .class files are located. This could be the /bin directory in your project.